# select query to calculate number of occurrence as well as total cost

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one report page which displays summarized data of other report.I have used php and mysqli. Let me explain you in deep.

I have a web application of store, where you can add product details. Using these product details you can generate packaging list report of products. And based on the generated packaging list report I need to generate one other report which contains summarized data of the packaging list.

below are my tables:

**product table:**

```
id | name | desc_id | purity | style_no | type | duty    
1  | ABC  |   1     | 18     | TEST123  |  R   | 100    
2  | XYZ  |   2     | 14     | TEST456  |  B   | 80    
3  | DEF  |   1     | 14     | TEST122  |  R   | 80    
4  | PQR  |   1     | 18     | TEST124  |  R   | 120    
5  | HJK  |   3     | 18     | TEST134  |  B   | 300
```

**Description table:**

```
id | descrip     
1  | Gold Diamond Ring    
2  | Gold Diamond Pendant    
3  | Gold Diamond Earring
```

**packaging_master table**

```
id | name     
1  | pkg_1    
2  | pkg_2
```

**packging_details table**

```
id | pkg_id | prod_id    
1  |  1     | 1    
2  |  1     | 2    
3  |  1     | 3    
4  |  1     | 4    
5  |  1     | 5
```

I have used below query to generate the packaging list report for specific id, which works correctly.

`SELECT id, (SELECT descrip FROM description WHERE id = desc_id ) AS descrip,` 
`style_no, type , purity, duty FROM product WHERE id IN ( SELECT prod_id FROM` `packaging_list_details WHERE pkg_id =1 ) ORDER BY descrip ASC , purity ASC`

which displays below result:

```
id | descrip            | style_no   | type   | purity | duty
1  |Gold Diamond Ring   | TEST123    |  R     | 18     | 100
4  |Gold Diamond Ring   | TEST124    |  R     | 18     | 120
3  |Gold Diamond Ring   | TEST122    |  R     | 14     | 80
2  |Gold Diamond Pendant| TEST456    |  B     | 14     | 80
5  |Gold Diamond Earring| TEST134    |  B     | 18     | 300
```

Now I want summarized data of above result using query.
Like:

```
id | descrip            | purity | qty | duty
1  |Gold Diamond Ring   | 18     | 2   | 220
2  |Gold Diamond Ring   | 14     | 1   | 80
3  |Gold Diamond Pendant| 14     | 1   | 80
4  |Gold Diamond Earring| 18     | 1   | 300
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `GROUP_BY` statement - See [MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) for more info.

This will translate the query to such

```
SELECT d.descrip, p.purity, count(p.purity) as qty, sum(p.duty)
FROM product p
  INNER JOIN Description d ON p.desc_id = d.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN packaging_details pg on pg.prod_id = p.id

GROUP BY d.descrip, p.purity
ORDER BY d.descrip desc, p.purity desc
```

You can also use the sub select methodology you were using, but I prefer using joins. `INNER JOIN` will link both tables so that all their records are returned. `OUTER JOIN` will return all rows from the tables on the `LEFT` of the statement and matches them to values from the tables on the `RIGHT`.

See a full [SQL Fiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29b05/17).

**NOTE: I am not sure where you are getting the values for Id in your sample - Are they simply row numbers?**

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is almost the same result I have required,but quantity is lacking into result.

Comment: Yes, row numbers, primary field, auto increment.

Comment: @pkachhia have updated to include qty.  The row numbers are not a primary field and should not be treated as index as the can change with every query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rewrite your query using JOINs:

```
SELECT
  P.id
  ,D.descrip
  ,P.style_no
  ,P.type
  ,P.purity
  ,P.duty
FROM
  packaging_list_details PLD
  JOIN
  product P ON
    (P.id = PLD.prod_id)
  LEFT JOIN
  description D on
    (D.desc_id = P.id)
WHERE
  (PLID.pkg_id = 1)
```

That should give you the same result you already have. To get the totals, you can write a new query, similar to the above:

```
SELECT
  P.id
  ,D.descrip
  ,P.type
  ,P.purity
  ,COUNT(p.id) as total_products
  ,SUM(P.duty) as total_duty
FROM
  packaging_list_details PLD
  JOIN
  product P ON
    (P.id = PLD.prod_id)
  LEFT JOIN
  description D on
    (D.desc_id = P.id)
WHERE
  (PLID.pkg_id = 1)
GROUP BY
  P.id
  ,D.descrip
  ,P.type
  ,P.purity
```

The second query gives you the totals you are looking for.

Comment: I have used your second query with some correction, but it gives me only one row, not as per my expectation.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot the group by. Answer modified, now it should be correct (it's funny that MySQL allows to run such a query without a GROUP BY, any other RDBMS would throw an error).